# How can I install realm cocoa converter for swift into my app project

Tags: realm

can anybody assist me in installing the new realm cocoa converter for csv files. How do I add it to my project? I downloaded it from GitHub here:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of the Realm Cocoa Converter. :)

At the moment, the converter only works for OS X apps, since it was designed to be integrated into the Realm Browser. So if you're looking at integrating it into iOS apps, it's not set up for that yet. We're looking at adding iOS support to it as soon as we can, but we're very busy on a few other things at the moment.

Aside from that, if you're running an OS X app, like Dejan said, you can install it via CocoaPods, or manually drag and link the dynamic framework into your app project.

Comment: is it still not available for use with iOS apps?

Comment: when it is available for iOS apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it using `CocoaPods` with:

```
pod 'RealmConverter'
```

But it looks like the current version `0.1.2` is not yet on `CocoaPods` - it's still `0.1.1`, but that shouldn't be much of a problem.

**Here's the whole info:**

```
-> RealmConverter (0.1.1)
   A library that provides the ability to import/export Realm files from a
   variety of data container formats.
   pod 'RealmConverter', '~> 0.1.1'
   - Homepage: https://realm.io
   - Source:   https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter.git
   - Versions: 0.1.1, 0.1 [master repo]
```

Comment: When running an empty project with RealmConverter installed I get an library error: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CSwiftV.framework/Versions/A/CSwiftV